# Passing a list of arguments (C++)

Tags: c++, argument-passing

I have lots of functions (it's actually an API) that go like this:

```
void func1(const funcData1& data, ...);
void func2(const funcData2& data, ...);
```

etc.

where `funcData1`, `funcData2`, etc. are only used for passing a list of arguments to the function. Every time a new function is added, a new `funcData89` is added too. This is not the best solution, IMHO. So I am looking for a more generic way to pass them. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: what is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: @user696807 Why is it not the best solution? What is bothering you in your current solution?

Comment: I can't rewrite the existing API. But maybe I can spare the never ending new funcData655. Also, sometimes a new member is added to funcData341. This means editing the .h and the .cpp of the class... Adding a setter and a getter, just to 'play nice' and calling it object oriented... Sometimes these things get wrapped in yet another layer, with useless setters and getters, for some higher level perpose... Bottom line: this is some convention used at my workplace, for no clear reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can either look into variadic arguments or pass the parameters as a collection:

```
void func (const funcData1& data, const std::list<Arg>& args);
```

Comment: std::list only contains a single type of args. I have several types. I actually thought about the variadic funcs. It will work, but might be confusing. For example, it will not throw a compilation error, when trying to pass inappropriate parameters. But it's a tradeoff.